# Indirect function in Excel - dragging down the column

Tags: excel-formula, excel-indirect

I'm working on a workbook that will have a master list of tasks for a group, and then each person within that group would have a worksheet with their specific information.  I'd like to make a few columns of information from those sub-worksheets populate back into the master list.

I think what I want to do is an indirect reference to the worksheet tab names.  The following formula works for me:

(B2 in this is a column that references the worksheet name, and E2 is the cell from that worksheet that i want returned)

*=INDIRECT(B2&"!E2")*

so, for example, B2 might say "Sarah", in which case the formula returns the value from cell E2 on worksheet "Sarah", which is exactly what I'm wanting to happen.

**The problem I'm running into is that when I drag this formula down to the next row, my cell reference to E2 stays the same rather than progressing to E3 like I would like it to.**

I have 3000 rows that I'd like to do this for, so manually re-typing the row # isn't sounding like fun.  Is there any way to make that automatically progress?

I'm pretty sure my issues are in those " marks, but I'm drawing a blank.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I did some more digging, and came up with the following solution:

=INDIRECT($B2&"!"&CELL("address",E2))

it seems to work.  It might not be the most elegant of solutions, but I'll take it!

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like:

```
=INDIRECT($B$2 & "!E" & ROWS($1:2))
```

We want to "freeze" he **B2** and propagate the cell reference.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I ended up going in a cell & address reference, but i bet what you suggested would have worked just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it didn't work because the sheet name contains one or more spatials. This would then work with: `=INDIRECT("'"&B2&"'!E2")`